# RAML Mulesoft Unsupported chars in string value

Tags: regex, mulesoft, raml

I am getting an error of 'Unsupported chars in string value (probably a binary file)' When sending a post request in postman. There is not a problem when I use the mocking service in anypoint's design center, only when I run in anypoint studio and post in postman.

raml

```
  id:
    type: string 
    pattern: ^\{\\"\w+\\":\\"\w+\\"(?:,\\"\w+\\":\\"\w+\\")*\}$|^\{\}$
    required: false
    example:   
     “{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":\"val2\"}”
```

I have tried to have the example have single quotes, double quotes and no quotes. It doesn't seem to like the slash before the curly brace.

I just need my regex to allow for these two scenarios (which the regex does work):

```
{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":\"val12\"}

{}
```

I am sending field in the request body as:

```
"id": "\{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":\"val2\"\}"
```

I think the problem is when converts to java its causing a problem but I am not able to figure out how I can send the string with validation and not erroring. Please help.

Comment: Are you implementing your API with APIkit?

Comment: Yes. I think using a regex won’t work for what I am trying to do so I am going to validate it’s escaped json in the code instead of contract.

Comment: I didn't said that but it may be simpler.

Comment: Oh, I know you didn't say that.. just what I was thinking that its not possible. If it is, please do let me know. Currently I am implementing by code change because I couldn't make the regex work in the contract. Let me know.

Comment: I suspect it can be done with regex but it is not the right tool. Validating the JSON sounds like a better match to perform the validation.